Compiler Design LR Parser
Writing a complier to determine if the following input strings satisfy the given CFG or not (1) "(i+i)i$" (2) "(i)$" my project builds but an exception is being thrown
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF883BDCF19 in Cpsc323Handout8.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0000004B15CFECD0
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

string table[16][11] =
{ {"S5", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "S4", "blank", "blank", "1", "2", "3"},
    {"blank", "S6", "S7", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "ACC", "blank", "blank", "blank"},
    {"blank", "R3", "R3", "S8", "S9", "blank", "R3", "R3", "blank", "blank", "blank"},
    {"blank", "R6", "R6", "R6", "R6", "blank", "R8", "R8", "blank", "blank", "blank"},
    {"S5", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "S4", "blank", "blank", "10", "2", "3"},
    {"blank", "R8", "R8", "R8", "R8", "blank", "R8", "R8", "blank", "blank", "blank"},
    {"S5", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "S4", "blank", "blank", "blank", "11", "3"},
    {"S5", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "S4", "blank", "blank", "blank", "12", "3"},
    {"S5", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "S4", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "13"},
    {"S5", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "S4", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "14"},
    {"blank", "S6", "S7", "blank", "blank", "blank", "S15", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank"},
    {"blank", "R1", "R1", "S8", "S9", "blank", "R1", "R1", "blank", "blank", "blank"},
    {"blank", "R2", "R2", "S8", "S9", "blank", "R2", "R2", "blank", "blank", "blank"},
    {"blank", "R4", "R4", "R4", "R4", "blank", "R4", "R4", "blank", "blank", "blank"},
    {"blank", "R5", "R5", "R5", "R5", "blank", "R5", "R5", "blank", "blank", "blank"},
    {"blank", "R7", "R7", "R7", "R7", "blank", "R7", "R7", "blank", "blank", "blank"}
};

void printStack(stack<char> charStack)
{
    stack<char> temp;
    char character;

    while (charStack.empty() == false)
    {
        character = charStack.top();
        charStack.pop();
        temp.push(character);
    }
    cout << "stack: " << endl;
    while (temp.empty() == false)
    {
        cout << temp.top() << endl;
        temp.pop();
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "LR parsing table!" << endl;
    cout << "enter input with '$' at the end.\n input: ";

    /*  "(i+i)*i$" "(i*)$"  */

    string input;
    cin >> input;
    int current = 0;

    // Push input onto the stack
    stack<char> charStack;
    charStack.push('0');

    while (true)
    {
        char value = input[current];
        int valueNum;
        if (value == 'i')
        {
            valueNum = 0;
        }
        if (value == '+')
        {
            valueNum = 1;
        }
        if (value == '-')
        {
            valueNum = 2;
        }
        if (value == '*')
        {
            valueNum = 3;
        }
        if (value == '/')
        {
            valueNum = 4;
        }
        if (value == '(')
        {
            valueNum = 5;
        }
        if (value == ')')
        {
            valueNum = 6;
        }
        if (value == '$')
        {
            valueNum = 7;
        }
        if (value == 'E')
        {
            valueNum = 8;
        }
        if (value == 'T')
        {
            valueNum = 9;
        }
        if (value == 'F')
        {
            valueNum = 10;
        }

        string tableVal = table[charStack.top()][valueNum];
        if (tableVal[0] == 's')
        {
            charStack.push(value);
            current += 1;
            charStack.push(tableVal[0]);
            // Print the stack
            cout << "stack: ";
            printStack(charStack);
        }

        
            /*
            charStack.pop();
            // pop() the stack | x | 

            // switch abd push reduction
            // charStack.push(tableVal[1]);
            */
        else if (tableVal[0] == 'r')
        {
            // Determine which rule is being used for reduction
            int ruleNum = tableVal[1] - '0'; // Convert the rule number character to integer

            // Define the resulting non-terminal symbol and the length of the right-hand side
            char nonTerminal;
            int rhsLength;

            // Determine the resulting non-terminal symbol and the length of the right-hand side
            switch (ruleNum) {
            case 1: // E -> E + T
                nonTerminal = 'E';
                rhsLength = 3;
                break;
            case 2: // E -> E - T
                nonTerminal = 'E';
                rhsLength = 3;
                break;
            case 3: // E -> T
                nonTerminal = 'E';
                rhsLength = 1;
                break;
            case 4: // T -> T * F
                nonTerminal = 'T';
                rhsLength = 3;
                break;
                // Add cases for other rules similarly
            default:
                cout << "Unknown reduction rule: " << ruleNum << endl;
                return false;
            }

            // Pop symbols from the stack based on the length of the right-hand side of the rule
            for (int i = 0; i < rhsLength * 2; ++i) {
                charStack.pop();
            }

            // Push the resulting non-terminal symbol onto the stack
            charStack.push(nonTerminal);
        }
        else if (isdigit(tableVal[0]))
        {
            // charStack.push(tableVal);
        }
        else if (tableVal == "acc") {
            cout << "input completed ";
            break;

        }
        else {
            cout << "ERROR no table entry";
            break;
        }       
    }
    // Print the stack
    cout << "stack: ";
    printStack(charStack);

    return 0;
}



I expecting my program to output like this
(
i
+
i
)
*
i
input complete

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

You should run it in your IDE - it will show you what statement the error occurs in. At a glance, though, you do charStack.push('0'); and then as the first reference to charStack within the loop you do table[charStack.top()], but table is 16 by 11 elements, so '0' is probably out of range.

FYI, you can use switch with single characters.  IMHO, it would make your code easier to read and take less lines.

FYI, character comparisons are case sensitive.  For example, 's' != 'S'.

The error occurs because here
string tableVal = table[charStack.top()][valueNum];

charStack.top() is returning 48, which is larger than the size of the table array.
charStack.push('0');

Here you push the character '0' to the charStack array. The character 0 is then returned by charStack.top() and implicetly converted to the integer 48, as 48 is the ASCII value of the character '0'
